# Some doubt on converges and divergences series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

One of tool for determinate the behaviours of the series is to check if $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$$ or $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}>1$$
But when the sequences $a_n$ converges to some $l$, the limit is not equal to the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$? So it's wrong determinate directly the $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$?
I don't understand why we must check the $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ and not $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close due to lack of clarity. Please clarify the body of your question so that it is not ambiguous.

Comment: Hint: what if $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: @user6247850 can give me some exaple when don't exists?

Comment: @afraidguy Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence where $\lim (x_n)$ doesn't exist, and define $a_n = x_n^n$.

Comment: @user6247850 but if doesn't exist, then the series is not indeterminate form? Like series of sin(x) or cos(x)?

Comment: @afraidguy I don't know what you mean.  If what doesn't exist?  What do you mean by "indeterminante form"?  What would the series being "indeterminate form" have to do with this question?

Comment: oke i understand what do you mean: you are told me if sqrt(a_n) has not limit, we must check for the sup because exists always. You can give some example when sqrt(a_n) dont exist but sup sqrt(a_n)<1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason that $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ needs to exist.  As an example, one could take $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ if $n$ is even and $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is odd.  Then $\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \frac 12$ if $n$ is even and $0$ if $n$ is odd, so $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ doesn't exist, but $\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \frac 12$.